# CLLocationManager "Turn On Location Services" Cancel Button press delegate

Tags: cllocationmanager

I want to know and take some action if the user has pressed cancel button in the
"Turn On Location Services" prompt. I have tried creating a breakpoint on the

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

delegate method but this breakpoint does not get hit.

I want to know if the location services is off and the user has hit cancel so that I may not get into the same workflow again and again.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution for that?

Answer (score -1):

Implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate's `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` method. When your app launches, the authorization status will be `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. When the user chooses Yes or No, this method will be called with a status of `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`.